# Getting tree to only list files matching a pattern and the directories they are contained in

Tags: tree

Is there anyway to get `tree` to behave such that, when it is run with the `-P` option, it will not output directories that don't have files matching the pattern somewhere inside of them?

As an example, take this directory structure:

```
${DIRECTORY}/
 runtime/
  runtime_library.so
  runtime_library.a
 my_libraries/
  drawing/
   drawing.so
  basic_functions/
   basic.a
 documents/
  manual.txt
 empty/
```

I'd like to get `tree` to output this:

```
${DIRECTORY}/
 my_libraries/
  basic_functions/
   basic.a
 runtime/
  runtime_library.a
```

Comment: My version of `tree` v1.7.0 (on fedora 23) has an option `--prune` to not show directories that have no matching files.

Comment: That's what I need, thanks. It's confusing that without `--prune`, all files are listed in blue and only matching ones in red, not very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you only want directories matching a specific pattern, so you need the `-P` option, i.e.

```shell
tree -P "*.a" --prune
```

The above will return all directories containing files with the extension `.a`. The [man page of `tree`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tree) can help you further. For instance, to ignore a pattern, you can use option `-I`.

The `--prune` option will suppress output of sections of the tree where directories don't contain files matching the pattern.